# windows bat file error

Tags: batch-file

i try to launch a BAT file on a network share but i get this error:

```
'\\dev\applets'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

is there a workaround for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have a chance to mount the network share first?

```
net use \\dev\applets z:
z:\mybatchfile.bat
```

Comment: ... or if you want to map it using the mouse, follow @RB's advice ;-)

Comment: thanks a good solution!  what if the drive Z is already in use? how can i catch the error and use another letter instead? this batch file should be accessible for many users who might have this drive-letter already.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the command-line processor to automatically map your UNC path to a drive when the batch script starts:

```
pushd %~dp0
echo %CD%
popd
```

When the popd command executes, or when your script ends, the drive will be automatically unmapped.

The only downside to this is that you still get the error message when the script runs.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to go without drive-mapping you can use [registry hack](https://web.archive.org/web/20170217024005/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/156276/cmd.exe-does-not-support-unc-names-as-the-current-directory) from Microsoft KB.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
      \Software
         \Microsoft
            \Command Processor
```

Add the value `DisableUNCCheck` `REG_DWORD` and set the value to `0 x 1` (Hex).

> WARNING: If you enable this feature and start a Console that has a current directory of an UNC name, start applications from that Console, and then close the Console, it could cause problems in the applications started from that Console.

Comment: works great for me to run a batch script in my \\psf\ drive in Parallels on OS X.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.. while the script runs just fine, the CMD.EXE header was annoying.

To supress that text, I simply call a CLS as a first line of my script.

This will remove that nasty CMD.EXE header and display whatever you want afterwards.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Mapped Network Drive. Assuming you are on Windows XP, the process is:

In a Windows Explorer window,

- Click `Tools`
- Click `Map Network Drive`
- Select a drive letter and a folder (e.g. `X:` and `\\dev\applets`)
- Click `Finish`

You can now just type

```
x:
cd applets
```

in your command prompt and run your batch file.

**ALTERNATIVELY**

You can also use the [NET USE](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) command to map the network drive. e.g.

```
NET USE X: \\dev\applets
x:
```

You can test ERRORLEVEL to see if the command completed successfully. Thanks to [this](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.batchworld/2005-01/msg00015.html) brilliant bit of code, I can suggest this solution:

```
@echo off
set alpha=zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihg
SET completed=false

FOR /L %%i in (1,1,23) DO CALL :MAPDRIVE

:MAPDRIVE
    set drive=%alpha:~0,1%
    set alpha=%alpha:~1,23%

    IF NOT %completed%==true (
        ECHO Attempting to mount drive as %drive%
        NET USE %drive%: \\dev\applets
    )

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET completed=true


GOTO END

:END
```

Comment: Assuming the name of the share he's mounting is `\\dev\applets`, x: will map directly to `shares`, so you don't need to `cd` into it.

Comment: Good catch - I'd just copied and pasted from my other code-block.

Comment: I can't try it here, but I'm quite sure that the "X:" needs to go after the \\dev\applets with `net use`...

Comment: @Jonas I tested that way and it works. Also, the MSDN article I linked to uses it that way round in the examples (e.g. `net use e: \\financial\letters`).

Comment: thanks that is a solution! what if the drive X is already in use? how can i catch the error and use Y: instead, etc. ?