# How can I map a \\wsl$\ type unc path to a windows drive letter?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, unc, drive-mapping

I'm using eclipse on windows to connect to files on a wsl, and I have run into what is apparently an eclipse bug which file names such as \wsl$\folder1\pom.xml get mangled.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=577938

A comment in the bug report suggests a possible workaround

```
A workaround is to map the UNC path to a drive letter, but this shouldn't be necessary
```

How would I do that?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d

Comment: Read the output of `net help use`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows bat file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949775/windows-bat-file-error)

Answer (score 8):

I did it this way (drive j: was available)

```
net use j: \\wsl$\Ubuntu
```

Note that this is persistent, and if not deleted can cause wsl2 to restart by itself.  After doing this I was able to access files on the Ubuntu distro from windows emacs.

to delete it:

```
net use /del j:
```

Comment: Also make sure you don't use a trailing backslash: `net use j: \\wsl$\Ubuntu\` fails. It also seems that mounting a subdirectory doesn't work either.