# UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

I am tryin to run composer install on my Laravel project. I use docker/Ubuntu to run my application. And every time I try to run composer I get this error(See error below)

> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC
> paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory. Composer
> could not find a composer.json file in C:\Windows To initialize a
> project, please create a composer.json file. See
> https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage

I think this error comes because in the path directory there is a $. (\wsl$\Ubuntu\home).

Don't know if there is a way to change the path or a work around for this error.

Hope this is anof information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows bat file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949775/windows-bat-file-error)